# matlab fxn: find contiguous regions and return bounds in struct array

Tags: matlab

This is half a question and half a challenge to the matlab gurus out there:
I'd like to have a function take in a logical array (false/true) and give the beginning and ending of all the contiguous regions containing trues, in a struct array.
Something like this:

```
b = getBounds([1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0])
```

should return

```
b = 3x1 struct array with fields:  
beg   
end
```

and

```
>> b(2)

ans = 

   beg: 4

   end: 6
```

I already have an implementation, but I don't really know how to deal with struct arrays well so I wanted to ask how you would do it - I have to go through mat2cell and deal, and when I have to deal with much larger struct arrays it becomes cumbersome.  Mine looks like this:

```
df = diff([0 foo 0]);

a = find(df==1); l = numel(a); 
a = mat2cell(a',ones(1,l)) 
[s(1:l).beg] = deal(a{:});

b = (find(df==-1)-1); 
b = mat2cell(b',ones(1,l)) 
[s(1:l).end] = deal(b{:});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why you are using mat2cell, etc. You are making too much of the problem.

Given a boolean row vector V, find the beginning and end points of all groups of ones in the sequence.

```
V = [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0];
```

You get most of it from diff. Thus

```
D = diff(V);
b.beg = 1 + find(D == 1);
```

This locates the beginning points of all groups of ones, EXCEPT for possibly the first group. So add a simple test.

```
if V(1)
  b.beg = [1,b.beg];
end
```

Likewise, every group of ones must end before another begins. So just find the end points, again worrying about the last group if it will be missed.

```
b.end = find(D == -1);
if V(end)
  b.end(end+1) = numel(V);
end
```

The result is as we expect.

```
b
b = 
    beg: [1 4 10]
    end: [1 6 11]
```

In fact though, we can do all of this even more easily. A simple solution is to always append a zero to the beginning and end of V, before we do the diff. See how this works.

```
D = diff([0,V,0]);
b.beg = find(D == 1);
b.end = find(D == -1) - 1;
```

Again, the result is as expected.

```
b
b = 
    beg: [1 4 10]
    end: [1 6 11]
```

By the way, I might avoid the use of end here, even as a structure field name. It is a bad habit to get into, using matlab keywords as variable names, even if they are only field names.

Comment: One side note... If you want to create an *array of structures* instead of *one structure storing arrays*, you could do this: `b = struct('beg',num2cell(find(D == 1)),'end',num2cell(find(D == -1)-1));`

Comment: i wanted to create the array of structures.  this is pretty much what i needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I went with:

```
df = diff([0 foo 0]);
s = struct('on',num2cell(find(df==1)), ...
    'off',num2cell(find(df==-1)-1));
```

I forgot about num2cell and the nice behavior of struct with cell arrays.